# Learning about @property

Tags: python, properties

I'm learning about properties, and wrote this code just to see how it works:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cities = 0
        self.time = 0
        self.efficiency = None
    @property
    def efficiency(self):
        print('Calculating efficiency')
        self.efficiency = self.cities / self.time
        return self.efficiency
    @efficiency.setter
    def efficiency(self,input):
        self.efficiency = input
```

When I tried to create an objet called `ejemplo` (example), I get `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` error. Anyone knows why?

This is how I created the `ejemplo`:

```
ejemplo = Car()
print(ejemplo.cities)
print(ejemplo.time)
ejemplo.efficiency = 2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Because your `property` has the same name as your managed attribute. Typically, you would just call your managed attribute `_efficiency` in this case

Comment: `self.efficiency = ...` calls the setter, because it's defined as a property.

Comment: So, in other words, in your `__init__` when you do `self.efficiency = None`, it calls your `property.setter`, which has `self.efficiency = input`, which calls the `property.setter`... and so on and so forth...